# Ubuntu 18.04 "Show Applications" Icon - Is there a way to control its size (width x height)?

Tags: icons

I am using Ubuntu 18.04
I have installed "Dash to Panel" Gnome Shell Extension.

I could manage to change the default "Show Applications" Icon to my choice as you see in the below pics.

I would like to know what is controlling its dimension? i mean any .xml file setting its width and height.

My Aim is to Control its width as per my choice if possible.

[image]
[image]

[image]