# How to change 'Show Applications' grid-icon in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, icons, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I'd like to change the size and background color of this icon. I've tried editing parts of 'App Icons' and 'App Folders' in gnome-shell.css, without success so far. Should I be looking instead into the ....symbolic.svg files in gnome-shell-theme.gresource?  Where are the specific files for this icon?

Comment: size as a rectangle or square?? related https://askubuntu.com/q/1050550/739431

Comment: Rectangle, preferably.

Comment: is the icon ready with you? to change the background color.. you need to have a perfect svg file.. otherwise changing background color is not possible..

Comment: related https://askubuntu.com/q/1123833/739431

Comment: 'icon ready?' Yes, the grid-icon works, but purely for appearance I would like to control its size and color.  Icons shown in the grid of the icon screen can be modified by editing the /*App Icons*/ section of gnome-shell.css and I wondered if something similar would be possible for the grid-icon itself.  I'll keep at this and will look into the svg files. Thank you for your responses

Comment: note that the size of the icon grid is hardcoded as square.. what ever the image you choose.. it will be weirdly adjusted to the square.. for making the icon to rectangle a gnome-shell extension is required which is to be prepared by a java script expert..

Answer (score 0):

[This Ubuntu Handbook article](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/06/change-start-menu-icon-ubuntu-20-04-lts/)  has since shown, for the Yaru theme, the location of this icon, and how it may be edited.

> The start menu dot grid icon relies on the `view-app-grid-symbolic.svg` icon. For default Yaru icon theme, it’s located in `/usr/share/icons/Yaru/scalable/actions`.

To change it, you can simply replace it with another SVG file.

Make a backup of the original file first:

```
cd /usr/share/icons/Yaru/scalable/actions/ && sudo cp view-app-grid-symbolic.svg view-app-grid-symbolic.svg.bak
```

Then copy the SVG file you want to use to the original location:

```
sudo cp /path/to/your/svg /usr/share/icons/Yaru/scalable/actions/view-app-grid-symbolic.svg
```